# How can I change component without changing URL in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ui-router

I would like to change component without changing URL. Let's assume that I have a component `register`. When I open my website I have url `www.myweb.com`. Then I would like to register by clicking `sign up`. I would like to display my component `register` without changing URL. Should I use `ngIf` or something else? Can you show me example how it should be done?

**UPDATE** I am sorry, but it seems to me that I was misunderstood. I tried
this solution:

login.component.ts:

```
showSignUp: boolean = false;
```

login.component.html:

```
<button (click)="showSignUp = true">Sign Up</button>

<register *ngIf="showSignUp"></register>
```

However when I clicking the button `Log in` I get this:

before:
[image]
after clicking:
[image]
After clicking the button `Log in` I would like to get a new website but with the same URL like this:
[image]

**UPDATE**
What do you think about solution shown below? In html file I will be checking whether variable `authenticated` is equal `true`. If so then I will display home component.

```
login() {
    this.loading = true;
    this.authenticationService.login(this.model.username, this.model.password)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                this.authenticated = true;
                // this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
            },
            error => {
                this.authenticated = false;
                this.alertService.error(error);
                this.loading = false;
            });
}
```

**UPDATE**
Unfortunately it doesn't work. Any ideas how can I use it with this button?

```
<button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">Log in</button>
```

Comment: Unless you objectively define what you mean by "more optimal", this will be based on opinion.

Comment: I'm just wondering why you would *not* want to change the URL?

Comment: @JamieR I would like to have it done in the same way as Instagram has. You can take a look on it. There is the same situation that I would like to achieve. After authentication they have still url `www.instagram.com`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `*ngIf` and show the component in condition!

#### examle

In your sign up component, set a variable and change its value on click of sign up button. And display your register component on click of the login by pitting the condition in display

```
// sign up component 

showRegister = false;
```

in your sign up component html

```
<register *ngIf="showRegister"></register>
```

Comment: Don't set variables used in templates as private. Production builds fail if you do.

Comment: I have updated my question because it seems to me that I described it in the wrong way first time round. Thank you for help.

Comment: you have to make another button for sing up and on click of that you need to show the register and hide login form. on lick of the login you are validating the login form and unless the form is valid you cannot do any thing else.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a perfect use case for `ngIf`. Try not to over engineer it.

Answer (score 0):

ngIf is the way to go on this kind of thing.

Just put in your component code something like

```
showSignUp: boolean = false;
```

then in template:

```
<button (click)="showSignUp = true">Sign Up</button>

<register *ngIf="showSignUp"></register>
```

And since you seem new to Angular, I'll mention that in order to use ngIf in template, your module needs to import the CommonModule like

```
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

imports: [
   CommonModule,
]
```

Comment: I have updated my question because it seems to me that I described it in the wrong way first time round. Thank you for help.

Comment: I read your revised question. Your approach to this is a bad idea.  You should leverage the router to make a separate pages for /login and /signup and then navigate to your home page.  Trying to keep the URL the same is a bad idea for a lot of reasons.

Comment: I have seperated URLs at the moment using routes. But I would like to have the same for welcome page which is a `login component` and `home component` which is a page that is visible after clicking the button `Log in`. Why in your opinion it is a bad idea? You can take a look on instagram. There is the same situation that I would like to achieve. After authentication they have still url www.instagram.com.